# Stopwatch with os.system(f"title")

Tags: python-3.x

So I would like for my program, to have a title bar that displays the time that the program has been running. I've tried many things but none seem to be working.
I would like it to be using **os.system** to display it but if there is a workaround I would use that I guess.

[Image on where I want the stopwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr2uv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need something like:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("My New Title")
```

This calls on a windows API to change to the console window title, but I don't know if this works with any other shells you might be using, especially as you didn't actually mentions if you are using windows. However I don't believe there is any other way to do it, in pure python at least.